# How to avoid nodes and edges overlapping and other display issues

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm trying to get some results while using **cytoscape**, with no success so far. The goal for me is to provide a very nice diagram (workflow chart) starting from data (either json, xml or other sources).

The areas I'm not succeeding are:

- Avoiding Nodes and Edges Overlapping
- Using all the available space (given a container my chart should occupy the entire space respecting the ratio)
- Applying a mix of Edges Styles to accommodate all the nodes in a well-organized way

The diagram is a read only for users meaning they will not be able to change how it looks (that's why I need it being nice when generated).
Users can only click on Nodes to run a specific task.

**This how it looks now**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNohX.png)

**This is how I'd like to have it (or close to)**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNTII.png)

I really appreciate any help as I'm very concerned that my knowledge does not allow me to take any further step.

Thanks!

Expectations as described in the images above.

Comment: This is cytoscape.js I assume? Try using Taxi edges for the desired effect.